# How to register an application as a Home alternative

Tags: android

I'm building an alternative Home application (a replacement of the standard launcher).

There's something I don't know how to make : how do you register your application so that it is called when the user click on the Home hard button ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It all depends on intent filter:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Ok ! I hadn't included DEFAULT. I guess that the combination of HOME and DEFAULT is needed.

Comment: AFAIK, you can skip DEFAULT if it's the only category.